# Where can I store this property for use by Maven and Java?

Tags: java, maven, properties

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 and Java 6.  I want to put a WSDL URL property somewhere that both the Maven build process can acccess and my runtime Java code (I'm building a Maven JAR project) can also access.  How would I structure/configure this?  In my runtime Java code, I have something like

```
String wsdlUrl = getProperty("wsdl.url");
```

and in Maven, I want to access the WSDL URL in a plugin like so ...

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <wsdlUrls>
                                                            <wsdlUrl>${wsdl.url}</wsdlUrl>
                                                    </wsdlUrls>
                                                    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                                                    <packageName>org.myco.bsorg</packageName>
                                            </configuration>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `.properties` file inside the `src/main/resources` directory.

#### Inside pom.xml

Use a [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html) and load properties from this file, like this (after the [usage site](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html)):

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>src/main/resources/common.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

#### From Java

Use [Properties#load(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) and load properties like this:

```
String propertiesFileName = "/common.properties";

Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName);

properties.load(inputStream);
```

Comment: Bear in mind, this does not work with profiles - if you change the path or name of the configuration file in the POM, it will not be picked up by the Properties reader. These are two distinct bits of code.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [maven resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to accomplish that.

Here is an example that will work for you.

`layout`

```
+- pom.xml
+- src
  +- main
    +- java
      +- resources
        +- application.properties
```

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <wsdl.url>http://some.url</wsdl.url>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlUrls>
                                <wsdlUrl>${wsdl.url}</wsdlUrl>
                            </wsdlUrls>
                            <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                            <packageName>org.myco.bsorg</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

`src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
wsdl.url = ${wsdl.url}
```

Then in your code you can load the properties file and get the property `wsdl.url`.

`src/main/java/com/company/Main.java`

```
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * @author maba, 2012-06-04
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader loader = Main.class.getClassLoader();
        InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        String url = (String) properties.get("wsdl.url");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing everything you list here but upon running "mvn clean compile," I'm getting the error, "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:1.10:wsimport (default) on project eodbclient: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException"

Comment: Run it again with `-X`. `mvn -X compile`. And also, check what phase the `jaxws-maven-plugin` is bound to.

Comment: @Dave I can understand that it is tempting to use some easy-to-use plugin to get it working but I always try to solve my maven issues with the standard maven tools. Also be aware that the `properties-maven-plugin` is in an alpha release. Is that acceptable by your company? It is also good to try to understand the whole concept that you are dealing with. My solution is working you just have to make sure that it is all done in the right order. The `jaxws-maven-plugin` is in a stable release and is solving a concrete problem so that is a feasable solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

src/main/resources or src/test/resources is accessible to maven and will be automatically massaged into the jar at build time.